# How to make a routinue and ask my son what he want

Tags: behavior, primary-schooler, screen-time

At the end of year 2, I had to take my son out of private school where he was studying since nursery, although it was hard decision but I had to make it because I was having financial issues, after new year began he sat 2 months in home as admission in public school isn't easily available,but he was very presistent in going to school.

During 2 months he was at home he least stuided or learn anything new, despite me buying him cool worksheet or books to read and reading with him. For him it is all day tv without brushing his teeth/washing face or go out with us for shopping, back again to watching tv. I tried to tell him we should study, learn new things, make timetable but it doesn't work. I tried to be hard on him but he just listen to ignore or do it for a day.

2 months later we got admission in public school, now 2 weeks in school, he became sick (as in flu, cough), it has been 3 weeks he been sick but mostly he told his mom that he don't like the school as other do not have manners like eating with open mouth etc.Mainly he has been very presistent that he misses his old school and friends (which is understable as he grew with them)

Why my son just want me to repeat everything and not follow, why is just wake up to watch tv and whole day it is tv, shopping or going out?
How can I make him undersrabd about why we choose different school because sometimes he act very mature and then ask silly question inbetween and if he want to homeschool then he has to make timetable? how can I make sure he follow a timetable and do not stray from it because till now I am failing to make him understand that tv is not life and yet he just say sorry and carry on.

I m structured person (not perfect), I had a background where when I was kid I use to watch tv like there is no tomorrow and I learned my lesson hard way but I do not want my son years wasted like mine. My wife and her family (where we live now) is not structured and my son knows my wife got her life issues to deal with and he gets away with it.

My son just turned 8. so everything above was few months before he turned 8.

Edit: As a father I feel insulted when he won't listen and lately he been not listening in gathering too, on the other hand he listen first time to his fav uncle and he has totally unstructured life.

Comment: As a father you must not feel insulted by a child's behaviour. They are learning how to behave. And you are key to teaching them.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you take your son very seriously. He feels that and it hurts the relationship.

Answer (score 3):

Your child will ultimately, in the course of their life, have to learn to get on with all sorts of people. People who are less academically able, and more, people who work hard and people who are happy to coast, people who eat with their mouths open and people who have impeccable table manners.

When you say he is sick, do you mean with a stomach bug, or cold/flu or is he just refusing to go to school? The transition back to proper schooling after two months might be a bit hard! Have you tried working with the school to ease him back into the classroom routine? An hour or two, then a whole morning, working up to a whole day?

I'd recommend persisting with the local primary school for a bit longer. See @anongoodnurse's response for more indepth response about the rigours of homeschooling

Comment: Rather than a blanket statement on what the OP is incapable of, perhaps stating what you think homeschool requires that the OP is not doing would be more helpful. The OP may not know what your expectations (or anyone's, for that matter) of homeschool are that he's "not cut out for".

Comment: I just updated my question with lot of more details cc @anongoodnurse

Comment: @anongoodnurse yes, that was too broad a statement, your answer provides a much better response to the homeschooling portion of the question

Answer (score 1):

Homeschool is not going to go well when it's the child who's expected to make a timetable and to do what they are told.

I understand I am not writing with knowledge of your culture, but children are children all over the world. If they are allowed to choose between *work* and doing something that provides *instant gratification*, they will most often choose gratification.

Homeschooling involves more than providing worksheets, books, and instructions; it requires full time *teaching and guiding the child* through all their lessons. It requires more than words of encouragement; you must sit there, teach the lessons, ask and answer questions, *then* assign work, and if the work is ignored, you must sit there and watch the child do the work until they are in the habit of doing the work without supervision. Then you check their work. This is for multiple subjects a day. If their mother or uncle(s) did not receive an education that mattered to them, they will not be supportive. You need to persist in spite of their lack of support or enthusiasm.

If you cannot devote that kind of time and attention to your child, they will not learn their lessons. and if their lessons are important, a better option is to require that the child attend whatever school is available to them without their agreement or control over the situation.

It's hard, but it is what it is. A child of that age must not define their own education; that's one of the roles of parents.